# Using expression in variables

Tags: r, variables, expression

I'm trying to label a plot in R with superscript. For example, I have a variable called label:

```
>label <- colnames(tmp.df);
>label
[1] "ColumnA" "Volume 100mm3", "ColumnC", etc.
```

I would like to have "3" in the "Volume 100mm3" as superscript in my plot label. I cannot use something like:

```
label <- c("ColumnA", expression(paste('Volume 100mm'^'3')), "ColumnC");
```

since the ordering of the column names in tmp.df may change from run to run. So how can I get around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could find the one with the *mm* by

```
ind <- grep("mm",label)
splt <- strsplit(label[ind], "mm")[[1]]
```

and then inject the expression via

```
label[ind] <- parse(text=sprintf("paste('%smm'^'%s')",splt[1],splt[2]))
```

If there are multiple strings that indicate the need for expressions, then it should be straightforward to adapt this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bquote` for this.  The `*` connects "Volume 100" to "mm^3" without a space.  If you want a space there, you can use `~` instead of `*`.

```
plot(1:10, main = bquote(.("Volume 100") * mm^3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

how about just using the Unicode character for cubed 'SUPERSCRIPT THREE' (U+00B3)? in R, this would be escaped as '100mm\u00B3', or if this is coming from a data file, just use unicode characters directly in the file.